# Will SQLSTATE ever be 00000 with a negative null indicator?

Tags: sql, db2, rpgle

Is it possible to have a negative null indicator with an SQLSTATE of 00000?

I am wondering if checking for both the SQLSTATE and the null indicator value is needed for certain operations, like an if statement. Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
EXEC SQL                                                                           
  SELECT 1 INTO :x1RcdFound:x1IndicatorVariable                                               
    FROM table1                                                                   
      WHERE value = :givenValue                                                    
       AND value2 = 'helloWorld';              

//this is where I am wondering if both checks need to happen                   
**if ( sqlstate = SQL_OK and x1RcdFound = 1 );**
```

Although this is a simple example, there are times when this is ran through a large loop, or multiple statements need to be used and saving a little bit of run time is helpful in the long run. This is part of an effort to write as concise code as possible, which is often overlooked in procedural languages.

Comment: SQLSTATE 00000 means successful execution, but you still have to check the null indicator(s).

Comment: IRL you don't need either check for what your doing.   Set x1rcdfound = 0 before executing the SQL.  Then the value is 1 or 0 after the SQL is executed.   (assuming a guaranteed one row result maybe add a fetch first 1 rows only clause)  Don't even bother to check the SQL result other than log the errors because the found flag is set to 0 or 1 already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a NULL value is possible, thus you need a NULL indicator, then yes, you must check it after getting an SQLSTATE of 00000.

However, NULL indicator's are only needed if a column could be NULL.

In the specific case you've provided code for that will not happen, you don't need a NULL indicator.

```
EXEC SQL                                                                           
  SELECT 1 INTO :x1RcdFound
    FROM table1                                                                   
      WHERE value = :givenValue                                                    
       AND value2 = 'helloWorld';
```

You're either going to get a 1 or you're going to get no rows.  Which is not the same as RS that contains a column that is NULL.

In fact, if there no rows, you'll get SQLSTATE = '02000' --> NO_DATA

Most code like yours I see takes advantage of the fact that if there are no rows, or if something goes wrong, the host variable is unchanged...

```
dcl-s xlRcdFound ind;

// note the definition of xlRcdFound as indicator
//   ie.  char(1) used as a Boolean.
xlRcdFound = *OFF;
EXEC SQL                                                                           
  SELECT '1' INTO :x1RcdFound
    FROM table1                                                                   
      WHERE value = :givenValue                                                    
       AND value2 = 'helloWorld';

if SqlExceptionOccurred(SQLSTATE:*ON);
  //report SQL exception
elseif xlRcdFound;
  //do something
endif;


dcl-proc SqlExceptionOccurred;
dcl-pi *n ind;
   mySqlState char(5) value;
   allowNoData ind value;
end-pi;
  if allowNoData;
     return %subst(mySqlState:1:2) > '02';
  endif;
     return %subst(mySqlState:1:2) >= '02';
end-proc;
```

Comment: It seems that it would just that much simpler to use an ind with the procedure, but would that create extra overhead? This seems like a good exported procedure that could be used within a company.

Comment: I don't understand the question about overhead....but yes, the example SqlExceptionOccurred() is a good candidate for putting into a common *SRVPGM.

Comment: As in, more processing power cost because of the exported procedure call every time you want to use it. Easily ten to fifty times a call depending on the amount of SQL.

Comment: the cost of a ILE procedure call is basically non-existent.  That is the whole purpose of ILE.

Comment: Thanks. I go between Java/RPG and in Java were much more worried about every line of code since GUI applications tend to take longer.

Comment: The only overhead in ILE is activation of a *SRVPGM or *PGM.  Make sure your *SRVPGM are ACTGRP(*CALLER) and that your programs use ACTGRP('MYCOMPANY')....that way a *SRVPGM is activated once per job..

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, since you are selecting a literal value, the only case when the result might be NULL would be when no data were found, in which case the SQLSTATE value would be `02000`. In other words, if SQLSTATE is `00000` then the result cannot be NULL.

Comment: That was my guess and hope. Thank you.